# Prestashop search by feature or tag

Tags: list, tags, product, prestashop

I need to make a Prestashop page which lists all products that have a specific feature or a specific tag, much like there is supplier and manufacturer product lists. I haven't been able to find a way to implement this though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `blocktags` module generates the list of tags, and search provides a list of products for a specific tag. Therefore after some slight modifications it is possible to create a list that looks and behaves the same.